# Correct method to call invocableMethod from Flow

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, invocable-method

I have a created an invocableMethod  that takes in a list of Work Orders

```
public class UpdateToAddressOnWorkOrderFromOrder {

    @InvocableMethod(label='update workorder ToAddress')
    public static void updatetoAddressOnWorkOrder(List<workOrder> orderList){
    Set<Id> resultIds = (new Map<Id,workOrder>(orderList)).keySet();
    List<WorkOrder> workOrdersToUpdate = new List<WorkOrder>();
    List<workOrder> woList = [SELECT Id,Use_AddressTo__c,Order__r.AddressToMunicipality__c,
                              Order__r.AddressToStreetNrLetterFlat__c,Order__r.AddressToPostalCode__c
                              from WorkOrder where Id in:resultIds and Use_AddressTo__c = true];
        for(Workorder w:woList){
            w.Address_Municipality__c = w.Order__r.AddressToMunicipality__c;
            w.Street = w.Order__r.AddressToStreetNrLetterFlat__c;
            w.Postalcode = w.Order__r.AddressToPostalCode__c;
        }
        try{
            update wolist;
        }catch(Exception e){
            system.debug('*** exception on woList update ***'+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

This class is supposed to be called from flow,

[image]

What do i do next to have the flow call my apex class after I've gathered all the work orders in a variable?

Comment: By clicking the "+" button, you can chosse "Action". Then, you'll be able to search for "update workorder ToAddress" and select your Apex method. Finally, check "Include" below "Set input values". You'll be able to send your workorder. Be careful because your method accept a parameter as a List of work order. If you want to send a collection from your flow, the parameter to send will be of type "List<List<workOrder>> orderList"

Comment: You seems to have Auto layout enabled. You can follow the above comment to add the action or disable the auto layout and you will get drag and drop components back in left sidebar.